# Passing an array as an argument to a method either results in a 0 for 1 error, or a blank array

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments

I'm testing a single-player blackjack program. I've made a `score` method that converts card names into integers, and then returns the total score from the `hand` array.

```
def random_card
  cards = ["two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
           "eight", "nine", "ten",
           "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"]

  cards[rand(13)]
end

hand = ["four", "queen", "ace", "seven"]

def score(hand)
  values = {
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4,
    "five" => 5,
    "six" => 6,
    "seven" => 7,
    "eight" => 8,
    "nine" => 9,
    "ten" => 10,
    "jack" => 10,
    "queen" => 10,
    "king" => 10,
    "ace" => 11
  }

  p hand

  final_score = 0
  i = 0

  while i < hand.length
    hand[i] = values[hand[i]]
    i += 1
  end

  hand.each do |card|
    final_score += card
  end
  if final_score <= 21
    puts "You scored: " + final_score.to_s
  else
    puts "You busted with: " + final_score.to_s
  end
end
```

The issue is passing the array to the method; it works when it's local, but passing the array as an argument either gives a 0 for 1 **ArgumentError**, or if I use the splat op, a blank array.

`hand` needs to be global so that the other methods can access it, like the `random_card` method that will eventually generate the hand.

When `hand` is inside `score`, `p hand` shows the full array, and the score is `32`. Where it is, a blank array is shown and the score is `0`.

How do I pass the array and keep the stored values?

Comment: Found the issue: I wasn't calling the method with any arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The issue might come from modifying the array - indeed the `hand` array is mutable so when you reassign values in the line `hand[i] = values[hand[i]]`, you end up destroying the original hand. A subsequent call to the same `score` method will not work anymore.

You should not mutate it but just iterate on it:

```
VALUES = {
  'two' => 2,
  ...
}

def score(hand)
  VALUES.values_at(*hand).reduce(0, &:+)
end

def busted?(score)
  score > 21
end

def print_score(score)
  puts "You #{busted?(score) ? 'busted with' : 'scored'}: #{score}"
end

def random_card
  VALUES.keys.sample
end

hand = Array.new(4) { random_card }
# => ["four", "queen", "ace", "seven"]

your_score = score(hand)
# => 32

print_score(your_score)
# "You busted with: 32"
```

Comment: Perhaps `sum` (new in v2.4) in place of `reduce(0, &:+)` (which could be just `reduce(:+)` (note no `&`). Alternatively, `hand.sum { |card| VALUES[card] }`.

Comment: `reduce` without initial accumulator won’t work if the array is empty. (`sum` would work fine)

Comment: Good point, though `reduce(0, :+)` is sufficient. Wait a minute. How could you have a hand with no cards in Blackjack?

Comment: I find that the “in this case it couldn’t happen” reason very faulty. Even in this case, you could have an automated evaluator that checks all hands, and making an empty hand a special case is not a good approach. Moreover I have seen too many cases of reduce applied with no initial accumulator, that Gail because the programmer did not think about the empty case. Better safe than sorry

Comment: The counter-argument is that if the array should not be empty an exception should be raised if it is empty.

Comment: Indeed, but in my opinion these are two separate concepts. Getting used to an explicit accumulator helps to understand the concept of reduction per se, and using a block instead of symbol makes apparent its actual behavior. Then when you implement blackjack, you can put boundary conditions and validations, without changing your usage of core code on a case by case basis.

Comment: In the end it’s mostly a matter of taste. Of the writer, of the reviewer and of the team.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is called *variable scope*. When you are accessing variable `hand` inside of score method, you are accessing local variable, which was passed as an argument. But you are want to access class variable `hand`.

You can call `self.hand` when accessing it (I do not recommend, because, this make your code even more smell.), or refactor the method score to return the array of scores and handle it outside of the method.